# how can we get network signal strength in android 1.6

Tags: android

how can we get network signal strength in android 1.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html)

[Code sample](http://osdir.com/ml/AndroidDevelopers/2009-03/msg04389.html)

Comment: I do not have a tested piece of code, sorry. Here is what I found though: http://osdir.com/ml/AndroidDevelopers/2009-03/msg04389.html

Comment: if the answer was helpful, please upvote/accept it so we both are rewarded for our effort